# Make Plone accept any HTML input

Tags: html, transform, plone, archetypes

What's the easiest way, in repeatable manner, to make Plone WYSIWYG and HTML input accept all elements and styles?

The use case

- Lot of private sites
- Trusted editors
- Advanced editors (able to produce hand crafted HTML and want to produce hand crafted HTML)

Plone element whitelisting is more hinder in these kind of cases.

Implementation

- Add-on product, with big button "disable all HTML security"

Since HTML filtering wants you to type in every CSS directive by hand, it is not practical in any mean. There must be a hidden switch to turn off all HTML filtering somehow?

Also is it possible to make unsafe HTML easily possible for Archetypes/Dexterity Rich text fields?

Comment: one button click in TinyMCE or CKEditor...just sayin'...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a big button, but it's not hard either. In the Zope Management Interface, at the top of a Plone site, go to portal_transforms and open the safe_html transform. Disable it by putting a "1" in the disable_transform field and saving.

This should not be done if there are any untrusted content authors or editors — or any naive enough to copy code from a third-party site and paste it into an editor.

Comment: There is a bug. disable_transform is cached for the life-time of Plone instance. Changing this value does nothing until the next restart. This was causing a lot of hair pulling.

Answer (score 1):

You now need to follow the linked post below by David Glick... but it's stupidly complicated and i gave up, instead favouring using customOverrides product to insert my js.

http://glicksoftware.com/blog/disable-html-filtering

Also, the Plone doco about this is wrong (http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/forms/wysiwyg.html#disabling-html-filtering-and-safe-html-transformation) and needs to be updated and in all honesty this sort of thing is an instant turn off for would be new adopters.

Comment: If you have a suggestion of how to improve the docs then you can edit and add a pull request [here](https://github.com/plone/documentation/blob/master/develop/plone/forms/wysiwyg.rst) on Github. I'm sure it will be appreciated